# How to mark some line to return with one key in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio

I want to place a mark in a file, then in any moment can return to the mark pressing some key.

Like <kbd>F2</kbd> in Notepad++

Comment: Visual Studio doesn’t have this as a feature.  You can write a Visual Studio add-on to accomplish this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support, but there are extensions providing the feature. To search for the extensions in VS Code:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to open the extensions pane.
2. Type e.g. `bookmark`.